# phpbb 3.2.5 Changelog/Timestamp for user rights / group membership

Tags: phpbb

Simple question: We are using a phpbb forum and I'd like to check when a user was added to a special user group. So I'd thought thought there must be a timestamp in the userrights or something like that, but i haven't found anything like that.

The main question I am trying to solve is simply: "In which month/year was this user added to a specific user group"

So before I delve deeper into the DB: Has anyone a pointer, idea, sql query or have had the same problem and solved it?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the ACP in the Administrator log?